# Tried to load angular more than once asp .net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting warning like "Tried to load angular more than once" while running my asp .net mvc project can one help me solve this

my app.js

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/dashboard1', { templateUrl: 'Dashboard1/demoOne', controller: 
'demoCtrl' }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }]);
```

my RouteConfig.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*catchAll}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home", action = "index", catchAll = UrlParameter.Optional
            } );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dashboard",
            url: "Dashboard1/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard1", action = "Empty" });
```

_layout.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                   <ul >                      
                         <li> <a href="#/dashboard1" > link1 </a></li>
                     </ul>

                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
    <div data-ng-view></div>

        @RenderBody()
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    <link href="~/Content/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/Scripts/myapp.js"></script>   
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing routes sequence:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Dashboard",
        url: "Dashboard1/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard1", action = "Empty" });

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{*catchAll}",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Home", action = "index", catchAll = UrlParameter.Optional
        } );
```

I think first route in your code handles all requests, and second route is never executed. Thats why when requesting `Dashboard1/demoOne` index file is returned instead of partial. You are bootstrapping angular in index file, so you are bootstrapping it twice.

Comment: i changed the sequence but still i'm getting same error

Comment: Check in chrome's network tab, what is the response when calling `Dashboard1/demoOne`